# How can I obtain some order in and multi-thread reading queue

Tags: java, multithreading

In my app, I would receive some user data, putting them into an ArrayBlockingQueue, and then put them into a database. Here several threads are used for **'getting the data from the queue and putting it into database'**. Then an issue came up.

The database is used to store each user's current status, thus the data's time sequence is very important. But when using multi threads to **'get and put'**, the order can not be ensured.

So I came up with an idea, it's like **'field grouping'**: for different users' data, multi-threads is fine, the order between them can be ignored; **but each user's data must be retrieved by the same thread.**

Now the question is, how can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use a HTTP-session?

Comment: Check out [Striped Executor Service by Dr. Heinz M. Kabutz](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is the number of Users limited? Then you can simply cache a thread across each user.

```
    // thread cache
    Map<Sting, Thread> threadcache = new HashMap<String,Thread>();
    threadcache.put("primary_key", t);
    // when accessing the daya
    Thread torun = threadcache.get(queue.peek());
    torun.start();
```

else

Java thread takes name Thread.setName()/getName. Use that to identify a thread, still reuse is something you have to handle according to your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PriorityBlockingQueue<E>` . `<E>` should be comparable. Implement logic such that that each user's data is individually sorted as per required attributes. Also use threadpools instead of managing threads discretely .